# iOS / Android Google maps API polygon altitude/altitudemode=absolute is missing

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, altitude

I am trying to create a polygon that has a specific altitude above sea level.
Easy in Google Earth. It seems that only 2D polygon i supported for iOS Google Maps.

Is it possible to read KML file into iOS/Android Google Map that describes the polygon (3D coordinate):

```
    <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
            <LinearRing>
                <coordinates>
                    10.86451916937838,44.19035448313407,500 ..............
                </coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>
```

Thanks in advance
Stephan

Answer (score 0):

Well, KML file is supported in the Google Maps Android API. The problem is altitude is not supported in the KML. You can check [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/kml#supported) the different supported features in the KML.

If you still want to show/view the altitude, then check this [Google Elevation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/intro) if it can help you.

Comment: Thanks. KML with coordinates that includes altitude works fine. I have just finished my app that starts Google Earth with a KML from my app. Problem is that the embedded Google map does not support 3D. Any way, I am happy that  Google earth does :-)